# react-big-calendar not rendering anything inside other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom, react-big-calendar

I'm trying to create some application with `react-big-calender`, but I'm facing some weird behavior of it. If I wrap it inside any other component other than directly rendering it, it doesn't show anything at all.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Cal />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Cal />, document.getElementById("root")); //<- works
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root")); //<- works, but doesn't show anything
```

And that `Cal` module is defined as it was defined in their [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-big-calendar-drag-and-drop-events-between-months-forked-nr1nr?file=/src/Cal.js)

Here is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-big-calendar-drag-and-drop-events-between-months-forked-nr1nr?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not related with `react-big-calender`, its the problem of `CSS`.

Try

```
<div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
  <Cal />
</div>
```